# Соединение с api сервера ангуляр2

Tags: api, post, angular2

Передо мной стоит задача связать форму регистрации с api. Отправляю данные post запросом, но данные отправляются запросом options. Как я подозреваю, браузер в целях безопасности запрещает кросс-доменные запросы. Как мне быть в этой ситуации? Я должна еще что-то настроить в angular или это проблема на сервере?

```
export class HttpAddUserService {

constructor(private http: Http) { }

postData(obj: AddUser) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(obj);

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

    return this.http.post('http://.../api/adduser', body, { headers: headers })
        .map((resp:Response)=>resp.json())
        .catch((error:any) =>{return Observable.throw(error);});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Серверу нужно добавить заголовок access allowed , так как запрос с другого домена. Помогла документация по CORS